# Why this code does print 28?

Tags: python, class, oop

This code prints 28 as an answer. I try to understand what's going on in the background, but cannot figure it out. I kindly ask, If you can, please explain.

```
class Geom(object):
def __init__(self, h=10, w=10):
    self.h, self.w =h,w
def rectangle(self):
    rect = self.h*2+self.w*2
    return rect
a = Geom(4)
print(a.rectangle())
>>28
```

Comment: `a.h` is 4; `a.w` is 10. Multiply each by two and add them together, and you get 28. Doesn't seem like it's that complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you have initialized the constructor as `a = Geom(4)` this means that the height `h` is set to 4. Since, you didn't specify the initial value for `w`, it defaults to a value of 10.

So, when the line

```
rect = self.h*2+self.w*2
```

in `rectangle()` method is called, it is calculated as

```
rect = 4*2 + 10*2
```

which results in an answer 28

Answer (score 0):

`a.h` = 4, `a.w` = 10 default;

`rect` = 4 * 2 + 10 * 2 = 28

Answer (score 0):

`a = Geom(4)` sets object **a**'s properties **h** to `4` and **w** to `10`.

Call to `rectangle()` on object **a** returns `self.h * 2 + self.w * 2` which is `4 * 2 + 10 * 2` i.e. **28**.